# Getting console errors when using jest.mock for React components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

When I mock a react component like this `jest.mock('react-slick', () => 'div');` I get console errors for unknown props passed to  tag. I know these errors don't mean anything in this case, but it's quite annoying to see them in the output:

[image: console.error]

Is there a way to disable these errors? Maybe just don't pass any props to the component when it is mocked?

Answer (score 0):

You can just mock the console.error, like so:

```
console.error = jest.genMockFn()
```

Jest will still fail the tests regardless of the above.